# PHP text lines to variables?

Tags: php, arrays, encryption

I have a php page that takes information from a .html page and writes it to a .txt file. As it was to write email data, I wanted it to be secure so added an encryption to it. I have one file that just writes the encrypted emails to a new line on a text file. I have a a decrypt function, but how could I run each line through the decrypt function (called "decrypt") then have it print out the result? So far I have...

```
$lines = count(file("emails.txt"));
$encrypted_txt = file("emails.txt");
foreach($encrypted_txt as $line_num => $line)
{
echo $line;
}
```

But this is just to separate each line, Is there a way to then run them through the decrypt function? I am quite new to php, so if you could offer an explanation as to why you use the code you do, it would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Please specify portion of the data from the `emails.txt` file.

Comment: "portion of the data from the `emails.txt` file."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($encrypted_txt as $line_num => $line)
{
   $decrypted = decrypt($line);
   echo $decrypted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question this should do the work:

```
$lines = count(file("emails.txt"));
$encrypted_txt = file("emails.txt");
foreach($encrypted_txt as $line_num => $line)
{
   echo decrypt($line);
}
```